# How to play H265 video on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

The documentation on Chromium's website (https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/) states that Chrome supports H.265 video, but I am unable to play it directly using Chrome.
For example, the link https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/720/Big_Buck_Bunny_720_10s_1MB.mp4 can be played directly in Chrome, but the link https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h265/720/Big_Buck_Bunny_720_10s_1MB.mp4 cannot.
My operating system is Windows 10 and my CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2225 CPU.
Chrome version: 114.0.5735.199

I need to play H.265 videos packaged in MP4 format directly using Chrome.